# In OpenCart checkout, how to change the names of months? I.e. "January" to "01-January"?

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, opencart

OpenCart 2.0.3.1

In One-Page Checkout, there's a credit card entry form.
Trying to change the month names - from "January" to "01-January", and so on.

Found the module responsible for the credit card form (authorizenet_aim.tpl), which has the following code:

```
<select name="cc_expire_date_month" id="input-cc-expire-date" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach ($months as $month) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $month['value']; ?>">
            <?php echo $month['text']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

So it's getting the **$month['text']** from somewhere, but WHERE? I tried sitewide search, and replacing every reference to "January" I came across, but it didn't seem to have a result. What am I missing? Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
<?php $month_num = ["January" => "01-January", "February" => "02-February", "March" => "03-March", "April" => "04-April", "May" => "05-May", "June" => "06-June", "July" => "07-July", "August" => "08-August", "September" => "09-September", "October" => "10-October", "November" => "11-November", "December" => "12-December"]; ?>
<select name="cc_expire_date_month" id="input-cc-expire-date" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach ($months as $month) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $month['value']; ?>">
            <?php echo $month_num[$month['text']]; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**What's happening?**

PHP is dynamically replacing the month names as their being echoed out by referencing an array with the keys of the undesired values and the values of the desired values. This allows for switching out the months without tracking down the source of the original array.

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. An answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how to fix it.

Comment: It worked, technically, but it made the page refresh UNBELIEVABLY slow. I'm talking a 1-2 second refresh becoming 10-15 seconds. On a checkout. Anytime any shipping fields / payment methods are touched.

So, it's a theoretical solution, but completely unacceptable in a production environment.

And I still don't know where it's getting those values from, originally.